# How to turn web app full independent from web api

Tags: c#, rest, api, model-view-controller

I'm developing and web app with services and for that i develop two different project one for web app and other for web api. Right now i'm stuck because i just use REST services on my web app but i need to fix a thing, the web app needs to be independent from web api so i don't want the web api dependencie on my web app.

So the problem is, in my web app files, program.cs and startup.cs i call the context from the API but i don't know if i need them and now i'm stopped because i need to get a way or know how can i turn web app full independent form web api but at the same time consuming the services from API like i have right now.

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MainContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole> (options => { options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "ãéabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+"; options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MainContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddMvc();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HomePage" });
        });

        //new UserRoleSeed(services).Seed().Wait();
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<MainContext>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

I will appreciate your help if someone help me or get some idea about this....

Comment: if you have a REST API it is independent from your frontend. If it is not independent, then you don't have a REST API.

Comment: @LucasWieloch what do you mean?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but you built your web app along with the API, and you have common modules being used in both of them

Comment: No, the web app are independet from web api and just use services to get the values